# How to calculate Project Phase cost based on interval date and daily cost table on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have two tables on SQL Server. The first table stores Project Phase data: ProjectPhase, StartDate, and FinishDate. And the second table stores Daily Cost data: StartDate, EndDate, and Daily Cost. Both table has a relationship using a foreign key column.

I want to calculate a project phase cost based on the start & finish date of the phase and the prorated daily cost. I have an example code as below:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(   
    [ForeignKeyID] INT
    ,[ProjectPhase] CHAR (100)
    ,[StartDate] DATETIME
    ,[FinishDate] DATETIME
);

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(   
    [ForeignKeyID] INT
    ,[StartDate] DATETIME
    ,[EndDate] DATETIME
    ,[DailyCost] INT
);

INSERT INTO @Table1 ([ForeignKeyID], [ProjectPhase], [StartDate], [FinishDate])
VALUES  (1, 'Phase 1', '20210101 00:00:00', '20210103 00:00:00')
        ,(1, 'Phase 2', '20210103 00:00:00', '20210105 06:00:00')
        ,(1, 'Phase 3', '20210105 06:00:00', NULL);

INSERT INTO @Table2 ([ForeignKeyID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [DailyCost])
VALUES (1, '20210101 00:00:00', '20210102 00:00:00', 1000)
      ,(1, '20210102 00:00:00', '20210103 00:00:00', 1000)
      ,(1, '20210103 00:00:00', '20210104 00:00:00', 1000)
      ,(1, '20210104 00:00:00', '20210105 00:00:00', 1000)
      ,(1, '20210105 00:00:00', '20210106 00:00:00', 1000);

SELECT 
    xxx
FROM 
    @Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t1.ForeignKeyID = t2.ForeignKeyID
```

I am expecting a result as below:

| ForeignKeyID | ProjectPhase | StartDate | FinishDate | ProjectPhaseCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Phase 1 | 01/01/2021 00.00 | 03/01/2021 00.00 | 2000 |
| 1 | Phase 2 | 03/01/2021 00.00 | 05/01/2021 06.00 | 2250 |
| 1 | Phase 3 | 05/01/2021 06.00 |  | 750 |

Thanks very much for any help or idea.

Comment: Explain how your startdate/finishdate and startdate/enddate are expected to be used.

Comment: For example, Phase 1 start on 1 Jan at 00:00 and finish at 3 Jan at 00:00. In the Cost table (Table 2), 1 Jan - 2 Jan cost is 1000 and 2 Jan - 3 Jan is 1000. So the total cost for Phase 1 is 2000. But for Phase 2, start on 3 Jan at 00:00 and finish at 5 Jan at 06:00, if we look at the Cost table, 3 Jan - 4 Jan cost is 1000 and 4 Jan - 5 Jan is 1000, but the finish date of the Phase 2 is at 06:00, so need to calculate the prorate cost for 6 hours, which is (6/24)*1000 = 250, so total cost for Phase 2 is 1000 + 1000 + 250 = 2250.

Comment: I see that but your sample data would be better with some varied daily costs to test that the value is being used correctly?

Comment: The daily cost may be different every day. I make it 1000 a day just to make easily to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to match the rows. This is a standard interval-matching condition: `start1 < end2 and end1 > start2`. You need to be careful with the logic around inclusive or exclusive dates.

Next, you need to calculate how many days. We need to do this in `seconds` otherwise we only get whole days. We take the later start and earlier end of the two tables.

Then just sum that multiplied by the cost.

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.ForeignKeyID,
    t1.ProjectPhase,
    t1.StartDate,
    t1.FinishDate,
    ProjectPhaseCost = SUM(
        t2.DailyCost *
        DATEDIFF(second,
            IIF(t1.StartDate > t2.StartDate, t1.StartDate, t2.StartDate),
            IIF(t1.FinishDate < t2.EndDate,   t1.FinishDate, t2.EndDate)
        ) / 86400.0)
FROM @Table1 t1
JOIN @Table2 t2
  ON t1.ForeignKeyID = t2.ForeignKeyID AND
     t1.StartDate < t2.EndDate AND t1.FinishDate > t2.StartDate
GROUP BY
    t1.ForeignKeyID,
    t1.ProjectPhase,
    t1.StartDate,
    t1.FinishDate;
```